# Where is the Carpet?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

So, I am following a walkthrough to play (I know, I know, shun me now...), and it tells me at this point I need to talk to the Carpet in the desert in Agrabah.

Problem is, I don't see a Carpet in the desert. All I see is sand, and when I try to look around, I just get lost and then I get dumped back at the Plaza.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you'll need to go to Aladdin's house and free the carpet, then it will be right in the desert by the save point. Check the video above to see where everything is specifically.

Comment: Ah, I missed the whole freeing the carpet deal. :D